# Prestashop: HelperForm with multilang field

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

where I use Helperform. I want to make some fields translatable. I added the following form:

```
        $fields_form = array(
        'form' => array(
            'legend' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('Diplom hinzufügen'),
                'icon' => 'icon-question'
            ),
            'input' => array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => $this->l('Name'),
                    'name' => 'name',
                    'lang' => true,
                ),
            ),
            'submit' => array('title' => $this->l('Save'))
        )
    );
    $helper = new HelperForm();
    $helper->submit_action = 'saveDiplom';
    $helper->currentIndex = $this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminModules', false).'&configure='.$this->name.'&tab_module='.$this->tab.'&module_name='.$this->name;
    $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');


    $helper->tpl_vars = array(
        'fields_value' => array(
            'name' => '',
        ),
    );


    return $helper->generateForm(array($fields_form));
```

I don't see the "name" field in the backoffice. What is wrong? If I delete 'lang' => true it shows up.
Is there any other setting needed (like in the constructor)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard HelperForm initialization:

```
$helper = new HelperForm();
$helper->show_toolbar             = false;
$helper->table                    = $this->table;
$helper->module                   = $this;
$helper->default_form_language    = $this->context->language->id;
$helper->allow_employee_form_lang = Configuration::get('PS_BO_ALLOW_EMPLOYEE_FORM_LANG', 0);

$helper->identifier    = $this->identifier;
$helper->submit_action = 'submitNameOfModuleModule';
$helper->currentIndex  = $this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminModules', false)
                         . '&configure=' . $this->name . '&tab_module=' . $this->tab . '&module_name=' . $this->name;
$helper->token         = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');

$helper->tpl_vars = array(
    'fields_value' => $this->getConfigFormValues(), /* Add values for your inputs, in your case you have passed the array directly */
    'languages'    => $this->context->controller->getLanguages(),
    'id_language'  => $this->context->language->id,
);
```

I guess you forgot the 'languages' in the `tpl_vars` array and the `id_language` too.

Maybe this [link](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+HelperForm+class) should be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @sarcom this helped me a lot! Sorry, I completely forgot to check the docs (only used google), normally they don't help :P

Comment: @EmanuelSchiendorfer You're welcome ;), I'm glad that was helpful :)

Comment: can you add the part regarding the postProcess

Comment: Hi @AliSamie, I strongly recommend to switch to the new symfony forms and forget the "postProcess" method  
You'll find all the info in the devdocs (devdocs.prestashop-project.org)

Comment: thanks @marsaldev but I am a little unfamiliar with symfony. do you think it is good to start learning that a little bit and then come back to ps+symfony ? or go straight into symfony? because I even could not make a modern backoffice controller for myself, or decorate one

Comment: @AliSamie as you wish, know a little bit of symfony it's not required but a very good plus. We also have a repository with several example modules where you can practically understand: https://github.com/PrestaShop/example-modules
